# How did I get hacked?

Tags: firewalls, audit, centos

As usual, I ordered a CentOS 7 virtual machine from my hoster. Installed a `firewalld` and `docker` on it. In docker, through `docker-compose`, I launched a web application that hangs on the standard port 80. And after a couple of days I found that my site was down.

My application works like this:
In my user folder there are two folders for the application - `html` - it contains the static files of my cms. And the folder `mysql` in which lies the database. The docker container is essentially an image of my cms to which these two folders are mounted (as I understand it, the web server works inside). Only port 80 is open outside.

```
# ls /user_folder
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile
html
mysql

# cat docker-compose.yml
services:
  web:
    image: octobercms/october-dev:latest
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:80:80
      - 127.0.0.1:3306:3306
    environment:
      - DISABLE_CACHE=true
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/october-mysql
    restart: always
```

I configured the firewall to only open port 80.

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 80/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

A few days later I notice that my site has gone down. I go to the server and see that somehow in the folder with the database there is a file "read me to recover data" and there is a classic letter in the spirit of "I encrypted all your data, send me bitcoins." I checked in the ssh logs that there were no logins other than my past. I checked the ssh logs, and the standard system message that says the date and time of the last login (I log in with ssh keys). I did not notice any anomalies in the application logs. In general, I am in deep bewilderment as with one open port - 80, they managed to hack me. I can assume that they somehow entered the CMS admin panel (although there were no logs), but I did not understand how they created files and folders in my system, and even more so how they got access to the database itself, that is, to the file itself. I checked the firewall, it was enabled. I understand that this description sounds insufficient, but suddenly I really missed something. This is my personal study project, so I'm not worried about hacking, but I'm wondering what I might have missed. Thanks for any advice

Comment: There was a vulnerability. What kind of vulnerability? We don't know. You are basically requesting a forensic investigation without the forensic evidence... on an unknown CMS.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Yes, I agree that there is practically no data, but it seems to me that the problem is that I somehow configured the firewall incorrectly and the database port actually stuck out. Because apart from the database, nothing was affected

Comment: You might want to look into the possibility that they came in through port 80, and exploited some known vulnerability in your CMS.  Have you checked if the version of the CMS that you are using has any known vulnerabilities?